# problems executing connection.createQueryDef in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, createquery

I'm new to VBA and I'm having problems using createQueryDef method with a connection object.

I'm just trying to create a query from a table that is in a SQL server database, simply to make the data appear in Access.
I opened the connection and then tried to use createQueryDef method, but it gives me a runtime error:

"Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable rangel, or are in confilct with one another"

Here is the code:

```
Sub connect()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
"Data Source=MyDataSource;" & _
"User Id=MyUserID;" & _
"Password=MyPassword;" & _
"initial catalog=MyDatabase;"

conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways

conn.Open

Dim qd As QueryDef

Set qd = conn.CreateQueryDef("test", "SELECT * FROM Mytable")

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "test", "C\MyFolder\test.xls"
rs.Close
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error on:

```
Set qd = conn.CreateQueryDef("test", "SELECT * FROM Mytable")
```

If you have another way to display the data from in an Access Table that works, I also appreciate your help, because that is just what I want

Answer (score 1):

[CreateQueryDef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243014%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is a method of a `DAO.Database` object.  It is not an available method of an ADO connection object.

If your goal is to create an Access query object and if you're doing this with VBA from within an Access session, you can leave ADO out of the picture and use a `DAO.Database` object to create the query with the `CreateQueryDef` method.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qd As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("test", "SELECT * FROM Mytable")
```

Comment: This didn't work because I don't have permission to use CREATE VIEW in the database, but I've found another way to do what I wanted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the ADO connection is to a non-Access database, so removed that part from answer.